# latex-preview-pane change page?

Tags: emacs

`latex-preview-pane` shows me the first page of the document, how do I generate all my pages? Or how to I switch the page I'm previewing? (scrolling doesn't work). I'm running on linux and doom emacs

Answer (score 1):

In Gnu Emacs on Windows. I can scroll through Latex Preview Pane with Spacebar.

[For more navigation options](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/DocView-Navigation.html)